# jQuery.getJSON Acess Denied

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, youtube-api

I am writing a simple bookmarklet that runs on youtube page and fetch some data from the youtube api about the current playing video. 
The bookmarket runs on Chrome and Firefox,but on IE(currently tested only on IE9) I am getting error from the next code :

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.getJSON('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + vid + '?v=2&alt=json',YoutubeBookmarklet.handle_gdata_obj)
.error(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    console.log(thrownError);
});
```

The first error I got was "No Transport",by the help of stackoverflow I saw that I need to add jQuery.support.cors = true in order to fix it,after adding it I am getting another error : "Access is denied."

I tried to use the IE XDomainRequest,but I get the same error.
What to do?

Comment: Javascript does not allow cross domain $.get's like that, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Hi,Phil,I don`t think you are right,If this is were true then my code won`t run on chrome or firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it using JSONP in order to do so i added "&callback=?" to the end of the url.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a cross domain call, take a look at this hope it will help you.

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Comment: I am trying to load it with $.getScript directly from github and I still get the error.

Comment: this hack doesn't work anymore. was not able to get it to work