# Retrieving youtube playlist info using JSON not working on IE

Tags: jquery, json, youtube-api, getjson, youtube-javascript-api

Below code is working on chrome and mozilla but this is not working on IE 8.

Could you help me out ..

```
var video_id='VA770wpLX-Q';

$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data,status,xhr){
alert(data.data.title);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because IE (until IE 10) does not support [Cross-Domain Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

`tkone`gives a good explanation here: [getJSON is not Working in IE for Youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338130/getjson-is-not-working-in-ie-for-youtube). Unfortunately the solution he offers (add a `?` at the end of the URL) does not work.

There are other solutions, an easy one would be to add `&callback=?`at the end of your URL, as suggested by [Yosy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958985/jquery-getjson-acess-denied):

```
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=?',
    function(data,status,xhr){
        alert(data.data.title);
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `$.ajax()` with `dataType: 'jsonp'` and jQuery will handle the JSON-P semantics for you.